# Making sure values do not get overwritten in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, overwrite

I am modelling the spread of a disease and I want to make an image which plots the first time an infection occurs in a pixel of a matrix.

So i got this:

```
for t=1:30
        infected=calc_infected(susceptibles, disease, row, col);
        if t < 8                            % The infection occurs in the first week in these pixels                       
           LM(find(infected > 0))= 2        
        elseif t>=8 && t<15                 % The infection occurs in the second week in these pixels
            LM(find(infected > 0))= 3;
        elseif t>=15 && t<22 
            LM(find(infected > 0))= 4;
        elseif t>=22 && t<30 
            LM(find(infected > 0))= 5;
end
```

T is the time in days. LM is my map on which I plot my data. Infected is the matrix which contains the temporal evolution of the infection. My question is: as I want to show to time the first infection occurs, how can I make sure that the value a pixel does not get overwritten when it becomes infected for the second time, but within another time classification? E.g. if a pixel has already a value of 2 because it got infected at t=5, but it gets infected again at t=25, it can get overwritten by a value of 5.

Thanks already!

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you should use logical indexing, `LM(infected>0)=2` (if `LM` and `infected` have the same size), and instead of all those `elseif`s you could also use a `switch`: `inds=infected>0; switch t, case num2cell(1:7), LM(inds)=2; case num2cell(8:14), LM(inds)=3; case num2cell(15:21), LM(inds)=4; case num2cell(22:29), LM(inds)=5; end`. You also forgot to treat `t==30`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized what you're trying to do and what your problem is:) If I understand correctly: `LM` is an array of the same `size` as `infected`, the latter is the binary infection state of a given cell, and `LM` shows the segmented time-evolution of the infection. Each class of values of `LM` indicate the part of the map that was infected last, and you want to keep track of the *first* infection time segment instead.

I suggest zero-initializing `LM` (which you should do anyway for performance), then check for the zeroness of `LM` when overwriting. Elaborating on my commented solution:

```
LM = zeros(row,col); % or the size if this is not it
tmax = 30;

for t=1:tmax
   infected = calc_infected(susceptibles, disease, row, col);
   inds = (infected>0) & (~LM);  % only consider LM==0 values
   switch t
      case num2cell(1:7)
         LM(inds)=2;
      case num2cell(8:14)
         LM(inds)=3;
      case num2cell(15:21)
         LM(inds)=4;
      case num2cell(22:29)
         LM(inds)=5;
      otherwise
         % do something if t==30!
   end
end
```

Note that I simply added `~LM` to the logical indices with a logical AND, which is short-hand for `LM==0`, i.e. it selects the zero indices in `LM`, just what you need.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough in the beginning, but that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `infected` output from the function, `calc_infected`, is a matrix that includes data for each day on which infections might exist, you can directly find the index of the first non-zero values in that matrix, using `[row, col] = find(infected, 1, 'first')`.  Then, as *@Andras Deak* suggested, you can use a switch statement to assign your flags according to the output for either `row` or `col`, assuming that one of them represents these possible infection days.  If the columns, for instance, represent possible infection days, then you would use the linear index in `col`.  If instead the rows represent these days, then you would use `row`.  That seems like the most intuitive approach.